# When I debug a C program with gdb, and key in 'p system', what exactly do I get?

Tags: c, gdb

Before I go deep into my questions, I need to confess that I am still fairly inexperienced to this subject, and am confused over quite a number of concepts, so please bear with me if my manner of asking those questions seems unorganized.

I recently learnt that as standard C library would be loaded into every C program we compiled (is this because we have #include  at the beginning of the source file?**[quesiton1]**), we would have its functions loaded into the memory. So, I would know that the system() function had already been loaded and stored somewhere in the memory, and then I was made know that I could find the exact address of where the system() function was stored by debugging a random C program with gdb, and issuing the command 'p system', which would print out the address of the function. I understand that 'p' is used to print variable in gdb, and 'system' in this case probably indicates the address of the system() function, so it seems to make sense to do so, but then I think to myself, wait a second, it does not appear that I have used the system() function anywhere in my code, why would the inventor of gdb include such a variable for me to print out the address of some function that I don't even use? and does this imply that the address of every function in stand C library can be found out in the same fashion? and they all have a corresponding variable name in gdb? **[question2]**

One more question unrelated to stuff I talked above is whether functions like system(), execve() and many others are specific to Linux OS, or they are also used in Windows OS? **[question3]**

Hope that you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *standard C library would be loaded into every C program we compiled* - This is incorrect. This depends on the linking phase of compilation. There are default libraries that are usually linked but this does not always have to be the case - see gcc -nostdlib.

Comment: You should ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 3):

The standard C library is linked with every program because it's necessary for it to be there to be able to run your program. There's a lot of things happening in your program before your `main` function gets called and after it returns, the standard library takes care of this. It also provides you with most of the standard functions you can call. You can compile things without a standard library, but that's an advanced topic. This is pretty much unrelated to `#include`.

Gdb can see `system` with `p` because it prints more than just variables. It prints anything that is in scope. `system` just happens to be a symbol that's visible to you in that scope. You could print any symbol that's visible to you, including all the globally visible variables and functions in libc and your program. Symbols in this context means "names of various things that need to be findable by programs and other libraries", this includes all functions, variables, section boundaries and many other things that the compiler/linker/runtime/debugger need to find to do its job.

Usually the standard library gets linked dynamically, which means that every program has the exact same copy of the library. In that case all symbols in it will be visible to your program because there's no reason to exclude them. If you link your program statically only the necessary parts of libc will be included and you would probably not see the `system` symbol unless you actually use that function.